# How to get the full URL from an Http4s Request

Tags: scala, http4s

I'm trying to obtain the beginning of the URL that a client used to access a webserver in Http4s. I.e. given a `Request[F]` I want to obtain the string `"http://localhost:8080"` or `"https://my-app.company.com"` depending on where the server is deployed.

In a server implementation with Http4s, when receiving a Request via something like

```scala
HttpRoutes.of[IO] {
  case req =>
    println(req.uri)
    ???
}
```

I only ever seem to get a relative URI, e.g. `/` or `/foo/bar` - the `scheme` and `authority` fields on the `Uri` are both `None`.

It looks like I can pull the `localhost:8080` part from the `Host` header on the request, but I have no solution for the scheme (`http://` or `https://`).

How can I fill in the correct value for `request.uri.scheme`? And is there a more appropriate way to obtain the `host`?

FWIW I'm using http4s 0.22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get it while using Blaze as an HTTP server. There are workarounds. You can catch bound of a server:

By port:

```
[io-compute-4] INFO org.http4s.blaze.channel.nio1.NIO1SocketServerGroup - Service bound to address /[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0]:8080
```

By schema:

```
[io-compute-4] INFO org.http4s.blaze.server.BlazeServerBuilder - http4s v1.0.0-M33 on blaze v1.0.0-M33 started at http://[::]:8080/
```

Or you can map 8080 to HTTP and 8081 to HTTPS and make pattern matching on it.

A bad workaround would be to add it as an HTTP header and read it via [Headers](https://http4s.org/v0.16/api/org/http4s/Request.html#headers:org.http4s.Headers)
It legacy practice but many legacy software companies are still using this approach.

---

Comment: Ok - backtracking from those logs you showed, it looks like those values are available on the `Server` instance that I'd get from `BlazeServerBuilder`; `address` for the "By port" example and `baseUri` for the "By schema" example.